# Proving intersection of POsets is a POset - Reflexive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, order-theory

I need to prove that the intersection of 2 POsets R and S is a POset.

So we basically want to prove that if $R$ and $S$ are POsets then $R \cap S$ is reflexive, transitive and anti-symmetric.

The problem is in the reflexive, I proved it like this:

We need to prove that $\forall a \in A ~~~ <a,a> \in R \cap S$
Because $R$ and $S$ are POsets, if $R \cap S = \emptyset$ then the intersection is reflexive (empty-wise)

Else, because $R$ and $S$ are POsets, if $<a,b> \in R \cap S$ then $<a,a> \in R$ and $<b,b> \in S$ because they are reflexive.
And thus $<a,a> , <b,b> \in R \cap S$  and thus it is reflexive.

> In the comments the professor said:  Reflexive is not correct, you
>   wrote that one thing is in R and other thing is in S so it is in the
>   intersection (?)  (-4 pts)

I don't know why I am wrong here, I would appreciate if you could point me to the mistake
Note: this does not have to be 'well written', we are first year students..I just need to find the logical mistake, not the semantic.

Thank you!

Comment: I think there is some confusion here about what the fields of the posets are. (i.e., what the underlying sets of the posets are). Can you quote the question in full please.

Comment: The actually question (and no I am not joking or somehintg) is: prove or disprove that the intersection of 2 partial orders is a partial order (There may be some confusion of the translation so here is the wikipedia of what I am talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set   - the first paragraph under "Formal definition" )

Comment: That's fine. It's true, but you have to take into account the possibility that the field of $R \cap S$ may be a proper subset of the field of $R$ and the field of $S$. I'll give some more hints in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: from the comments, there is no constraint on the underlying sets of the posets $R$ and $S$. As you have noted, you can prove reflexivity and antisymmetry of $R \cap S$ without constraining the underlying set (or *field*) of this relation. For reflexivity, what you have to prove is that for every $x$ in the field of the relation $R \cap S$, $\langle x, x \rangle \in R \cap S$. Your argument is right if you define $A$ to be the field of $R \cap S$ (although you might want to improve the phrasing - you have correctly identified the conditions for $a$ or $b$ to be in the field of $R \cap S$). I don't think your professor's comments are very helpful: the right comment is "what's $A$?". Maybe he or she thought they'd asked a question about posets $R$ and $S$ over the same field, but, apparently, they did not.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your answer. In the question they did not specify on what R or S are ( If that makes sense - because I know that a poset needs to be onto some set, A) so I took a random set A . Should I appeal? thank you again!

Comment: I think you should certainly discuss the point with your professor.

Comment: Thank you sir, much appreciated!